# SwiftUI: Resize text to fit button

Tags: button, text, styles, swiftui

I am updating button text based on values in a database and as these values may be very long or very short, I want the button size to remain constant and the text to resize dynamically depending on how big the value is, so it remains within the button and not truncated (The values will be sentences, it is a language learning app). I basically want to give the font size a minimum possible value and a maximum possible value.

I know how to do this in Android Studio.

```
autoSizeMinTextSize=14sp
autoSizeMaxTestSize=20sp
```

But when I tried to use suggestions like a large font size with minimumScaleFactor, it doesn't work. It just makes the text incredibly small.

Here is my button style.

```
struct SoundButton: ButtonStyle {

    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .font(.custom("arial", size: 20))
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(configuration.isPressed ? LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("DarkestGreen"), Color("LightGreen")]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom):LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("DarkGreen"), Color("LightGreen")]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .shadow(radius: 3.0)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth:2))
            .padding(2)
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.975 : 1.0)
    }
}
```

And here is the button code.

```
                        Button(action: {
                            playSound(sound: "\(self.category)_audio1", type: "mp3")
                            self.translation = self.btns[1][1]
                        }) {
                            if(gotValues==true) {
                                Text("\(self.btns[1][0])")
                            } else {
                                Text("\(self.btn1)")
                            }
                        }
```

Here is what my screen looks like in the app.

[image]

What can I add to this to achieve the desired effect? Thank you.

Also, here is the working android version.

[image]

Comment: But you don't limit button size anyhow? The `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)` allows to grow it no-limit intentionally. So?

Comment: I have 16 buttons. I want them to divide up the screen equally within their parent view. They are constraining each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understood your goal the following should give you required effect (or sort of)...

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

```swift
configuration.label
    .padding(.horizontal, 8).lineLimit(1).minimumScaleFactor(0.4) // << this place !
    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
```

Comment: I tried but the lines are very small and do not fill up the button. The font size is identical on every button too. I've added a screenshot of the working android version to my original post.

Comment: If you need wrapped text (that was not obvious), just remove `.lineLimit` modifier in proposed answer.

Comment: If I remove the line limit and change the scalefactor to 0.8 it looks more like the android version but it still doesn't alter the size of the text across buttons. All the buttons have the same font size. minimumScaleFactor just seems to mean scale factor. If I change the font size to 16 it looks exactly the same. But in your screenshot the font size is changing. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: SwiftUI does not have such thing as `autoSizeMinTextSize`, at least for now, if expected that. You can submit feedback to Apple with suggestion. And about `minimumScaleFactor` - here from doc *The minimum permissible proportion to shrink the font size to fit the text into the available space*, so it is not kind of "regular scale", it changes font size.

Comment: Yeah it's just that it is shrinking font size when it doesn't need too. But yours is allowing the font size to be different. What else do you have in configuration.label?